# only to increment when the row is not empty

Tags: c++, loops, vector

I am populating a `table` with a `vector` however there are some `empty cells` in the `vector` and i want to only `create` a `new row` if a `cell` is `not empty` but the table does not like this because it wants the row numbers to `increment` by one

i.e
**1,2,3,4,5**

if it is `empty` it will be like THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
**1,2,4,5**

So how can i get it to not `increment` when a cell is `empty` and only wen a `cell` has content in there so it stays like

**1,2,3,4,5**

code

```
int it = 0;
        while(it < popLocatedErrorColumn.size())
        {
            if(popLocatedErrorColumn[it] != "")
            {
                DCS_GET_HTMLKIT_REPETITION(uldtable, uldRow,NULL,it);
                if(uldRow.getItem("locatedError"))
                    uldRow.getItem("locatedError")->setValue(popLocatedErrorColumn[it]);
            }
            it++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a second integer index to keep track of the current row number.

```
    int it = 0, index = 0; 
    while(it < popLocatedErrorColumn.size())
    {
        if(popLocatedErrorColumn[it] != "")
        {
            DCS_GET_HTMLKIT_REPETITION(uldtable, uldRow,NULL,index);
            index++;
            if(uldRow.getItem("locatedError"))
                uldRow.getItem("locatedError")->setValue(popLocatedErrorColumn[it]);
        }
        it++;
    }
```